# Sort a List<String[]> by indices using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a CSV file and I need to sort the content by two columns. The first column is a date and the fourth is text. I need that file sorted by first and fourth column.
I'm trying like this:

```
//i read file and iterate in lines
PriorityQueue<String[]> linesOrdenered = new PriorityQueue<>(new LineComparator());
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(CVS_SPLIT_BY);
                if ((!isHeader) && row[0].equals("Route Date")) {
                    header = line;
                    isHeader = true;
                    continue;
                }
                linesOrdenered.add(row);
            }


public class LineComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
        //string[3] == key
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] strings, String[] t1) {
            int keyComparator = 0;
            try {
                Date dataOne = format.parse(strings[0]);
                Date dataTwo = format.parse(t1[0]);
                keyComparator = dataOne.compareTo(dataTwo);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error on parse Data [{}]", e.getMessage());
            }
            if (keyComparator == 0) {
                keyComparator = strings[3].compareTo(t1[3]);
            }
            return keyComparator;
        }

    }
```

The result is a PriorityQueue with just date being ordered.
Example content of CSV file:

```
12/01/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/03/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/04/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/05/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/01/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/03/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/04/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/05/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/06/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/07/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file and "format" are not available for us but my educated guess is that all dates are different when parsed using the format (at least to the extent that comparing them does not return 0).

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on with Roy Shahaf's idea, assuming :

```
private static DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I get:

```
12/01/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/01/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/03/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/03/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/04/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/04/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/05/2018,6:30,C-993BNT,A1001
12/05/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/06/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
12/07/2018,6:30,C-555BQJ,A1003
```

which looks right to me. see https://jdoodle.com/a/QXP